# Firebase error: Assertion failed resolving hosting target of a site with no site name or target name

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I'm going through the Firebase tutorial for create a "FriendlyChat" web app.  I made it to
[Step 6](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web#5).

At this point, it tells you to run the following command

```
firebase emulators:start
```

When I do this, however, I get an error.

> firebase emulators:start
> i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, functions, firestore, hosting, storage
> i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.
> i  hub: Stopping emulator hub

Error: Assertion failed: resolving hosting target of a site with no site name or target name. This should have caused an error earlier

I've looked at my firebase.json file and see the following for hosting.  Is there something wrong here?

```
  "hosting": [
    {
      "source": ".",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "frameworksBackend": {
        "region": "us-central1"
      }
    },
    {
      "target": "friendlychat",
      "source": ".",
      "frameworksBackend": {}
    }
  ],
```

Per the tutorial instructions, running the command "firebase emulators:start" should have resulted in the following response.   hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5000.  Instead, I get the described error.